# Is there a way to compare SQL Server 2012 results with an entire UI grid in TestComplete?

Tags: sql-server-2012, jscript, testcomplete

I'm using JScript and SQL Server 2012 to verify a grid in a UI.

Is there a way to compare SQL results to a single column? The entire grid is mapped, but nothing else. Even with the Map Object From Screen tool, I can't highlight a single row or column.

I've searched every property and mapped item I could find, but nothing get me closer to what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate rows, columns or cells are not UI objects. Using TestComplete, you can create a Table checkpoint and specify that only a single column should be verified. More information on table checkpoints in TestComplete can be found in the [About Table Checkpoints](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/80873/) help topic.

Comment: Thank you.I'm using scripts for testing, and I saw the Check method for Table objects in the link you provided. If I'm trying to verify grid results based on query results, do you know if this method would be appropriate? I've used the CompareProperty for other tests, but I'd like to verify the sort order if it's possible. On previous projects, I was at least able to focus on a single column, but in this project, only the entire grid is mapped; I can't even focus on one column to verify results. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Dan, yes, if the grid you work with is supported by TestComplete, you should  be able to validate data in it using a Table Checkpoint.